# Equivalent expressions of the trace class norm on infinite dimensional separable Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space. Suppose $A$ is a trace class operator on $H$, i.e., $A$ is a compact operator such that
$$\Vert A\Vert_{tr}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s_n(A)<\infty$$
where $s_n(A)$ are singular values of $A$, i.e., eigenvalues of the square root of $A^*A$. My question is whether the following relation holds:
$$\Vert A\Vert_{tr}=\sup\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(Ae_n,e_n)|\Big|\ \{e_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \ \mbox{is an orthonormal basis of $H$}\right\}.$$
Moreover, I have already verified that
$$\Vert A\Vert_{tr}=\sup\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(Ae_n,f_n)|\Big|\ \{e_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty},\{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \ \mbox{are orthonormal bases of $H$}\right\}.$$
And I am also curious about if there are other equivalent expressions. Thanks in advance for your kind help!!

Comment: Are you sure that it is $(Ae_n, f_n)$ and not $(|A|e_n,f_n)$? (where $|A|=(A^*A)^{1/2}$)

Comment: Yeah. This can be obtained by applying the spectra decomposition of $A$, i.e., $A=\sum_n s_n(\cdot, e_n)f_n$, where $\{e_n\}$ and $\{f_n\}$ are orthonomrmal families. Thus $\sum_n|(Ae_n,f_n)|=\sum_n s_n=\Vert A\Vert_{tr}$.

Comment: Well, The definition of the trace norm i know is from Murphy's book and it is $\|A\|_{tr}:=\sum_{x\in E}\langle |A|x,x\rangle$ where $E$ is an ONB of the Hilbert space. Yes, this equality implies independence of the sum from the ONB.

Comment: Okay! I will check with that book. Thanks for your kind help!!

Answer (score 1):

As for the first definition, I have discovered a counter-example.
$$\Vert A-A^*\Vert=\sup\left\{\sum_n|(Ae_n,e_n)-(A^*e_n,e_n)|\right\}=0,$$
which is a contradiction, since the above relation means $A=A^*$ for any trace class operator. So I think the first equivalent definition does not hold at least in the real Hilbert space.

As for the second definition, i.e.,
$$\Vert A\Vert_{tr}=\sup\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|(Ae_n,f_n)|\Big|\ \{e_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty},\{f_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty} \ \mbox{are orthonormal bases of $H$}\right\},$$
it could be obtained via the spectra decomposition of $A$. First, we take the polar decomposition of $A$, i.e.,
$$A=Q|A|$$
where $Q$ is the partial isometry on $\overline{\mathcal{R}|A|}$. Then, we obtain
$$A=\sum_ns_n(\cdot, e_n)Qe_n.$$ where $\{e_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is the orthonormal basis induced by $A^*A$. Since $Q$ is partial isometry, then $\{Qe_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal family. Then
$$\sum_n|(Ae_n,Qe_n)|=\sum_n s_n=\Vert A\Vert_{tr}.$$
And we are left to verify
$$\Vert A\Vert_{tr}\ge \sum_{n}|(Ae_n^{'},f_n^{'})|$$
for any orthonormal bases $\{e_n^{'}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{f_n^{'}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Again by applying the spectra decompostion and the Bessel's inequality, we get
$$\sum_n|(Ae_n^{'},f^{'}_n)|=\sum_n\left|\left(\sum_ks_k(e_n^{'},e_k)Qe_k,f_n^{'}\right)\right|\le\sum_k\sum_n\left|s_k(e_n^{'},e_k)\left(Qe_k,f_n^{'}\right)\right|\le\sum_ks_k\left(\sum_n\left|(e_n^{'},e_k)\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\sum_n\left|\left(Qe_k,f_n^{'}\right)\right|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le\sum_ks_k=\Vert A\Vert_{tr}$$
as claimed.

And could anyone supply other equivalent definition of the trace norm? Thanks a lot!!!